# Datagridview correct row is selected but the arrow is still pointing at the first record

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have programmed my `DataGridView` so that when a new record is inserted, the selected index will change to that newly created record. But the arrow is still pointing at the first row. This is the LINQ code I use.

```
int selectedRowIndex = 0;
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewFtpServers.Rows
                            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .Where(r => r.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString().Equals(selectedId.ToString()))
                            .First();
selectedRowIndex = row.Index;
dataGridViewFtpServers.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Selected = true;
```

How can I point the arrow to my `selectedRowIndex` so that I don't get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black triangle cursor follows the [CurrentRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

The current row property is read only but as noted in msdn:

> To change the current row, you must set the CurrentCell property to a
>   cell in the desired row.

Comment: can you write a line to do that?

Comment: this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[1,selectedRowIndex]; for column 1, Row selectedRowIndex.

Comment: Setting CurrentCell leaves me with the same issue I had when I was setting the cell to .Selected.  The Cursor (Arrow) and the highlighted cell are not congruent.